# Inkcanvas Stroke Top,Left,Right,Bottom Location

Tags: inkcanvas

In inkcanvas I can able to draw the stroke ,where i want to find the location(Top,Left,Right.Bottom) of the stroke.
  If the stroke is drawn at the Top of the inkcanvas control,then stroke location is at Top.
 How to find this as i am using getBounds() it is not helping me to find the Top location of the drawn Strokes

Answer (score 0):

`GetBounds()` is working for me. In my case I'm intercepting the InkCanvas StrokeCollected event and doing:

```
Rect bounds = e.Stroke.GetBounds();
```

It gives me the top, left, right, and bottom.

If you need the locations of individual points such as the first or last, you can use the StylusPoints property of the collected stroke to access them.